# Is there still inline javascript code as saying in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, inline

```
<button onclick = "alert('click the Button!');"> Click me !</button>
```

these line in old HTML,  is this code still named as

> inline javascipt

?

Comment: You could have easily tried it to find your answer.

Comment: Are you asking if it's still *possible*, or if that's still what it's called?

Comment: is that still that kind of called?

Comment: https://dev.to/chiefoleka/how-to-use-inline-javascript-with-html-you-definitely-like-really-bad-code-1a1o

Answer (score 2):

Inline JavaScript is when a `<script>` tag directly contains JavaScript code (instead of loading it from an external source referred by its `src` attribute).

What you show is an [onevent handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers), at least MDN calls them that way.